# How to adjust KML coordinates

Tags: kml

I'm looking at some KML files for the Western Pacific.
Usually the longitude stops at 180 degrees, but the coordinates they have
are like, partial:

```
188.000,-15.268,0 188.110,-15.270,0 188.220,-15.276,0 188.330,-15.286,0 188.439,-15.300,0
```

If I point Google Earth at it, it renders it fine.
Without any "conversion" I can't render them.
So what do I need to do to get them in the "right" range so I can
render them?

Something like this?

```
If > 180:
X = Long_Val - 180;
Y = 180 - X;
```

** UPDATE **
Upon some further looking around, I think I found what I was looking for.  They called it normalizing the Longitude, and I guess it applies when it's > 180.

One formula was like this:

```
double dLatX = (200.217 % 360 + 360 + 180) % 360 - 180;
```

Where "200.217" was the Longitude.
It comes out to:    `dLatX: -159.78300000000002`
I still have to see if it's in the right area.